# Fourier transform and splitting frequency range into 4 channels

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis, logarithms, fourier-series, signal-processing

I have code example that divides audio frequency into 6 channels.
It uses Fast Fourier Transform (FFT). Algorithm process the frequency range using 6 capture[x] samples based on the range of n between 0 and 63. The separation looks logarithmic. I want modify code to split frequency band into 4 channels, so I need to change the boundaries here. What should be the new values for 4 channels? Problem is that I don't know what is corresponding frequency range to each value.
The existing divisions use:

```
           # of samples
1) 0             1
2) 1..3          3
3) 4..11         8
4) 12..21       10
5) 22..34       13
6) 35..63       29
```

code

```
for (uint8_t n = 0; n < FFT_N / 2; n++) {
    s = spektrum[n];

    if(n == 0) {                                            // lowest frequency band
        if(s <= SCORE_MAX) capture[0] = s;
        else capture[0] = SCORE_MAX;
    }

    if((n >= 1)  && (n <= 3)) {
        if((capture[1] + s) <= SCORE_MAX) capture[1] += s;
        else capture[1] = SCORE_MAX;
    }

    if((n >= 4)  && (n <= 11)) {
        if((capture[2] + s) <= SCORE_MAX) capture[2] += s;
        else capture[2] = SCORE_MAX;
    }

    if((n >= 12) && (n <= 21)) {
        if((capture[3] + s) <= SCORE_MAX) capture[3] += s;
        else capture[3] = SCORE_MAX;
    }

    if((n >= 22) && (n <= 34)) {
        if((capture[4] + s) <= SCORE_MAX) capture[4] += s;
        else capture[4] = SCORE_MAX;
    }

    if((n >= 35) && (n <= 63)) {                            // highest frequency band
        if((capture[5] + s) <= SCORE_MAX) capture[5] += s;
        else capture[5] = SCORE_MAX;
    }
}
```

Full code [here](http://pastebin.com/vsuSrruW).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $N$ is the FFT length, which I assume is $128$ in your example, then the frequency corresponding to the FFT bin with index $i$ is given by

$$f_i=\frac{if_s}{N},\quad i=0,1,\ldots, N/2\tag{1}$$

where $f_s$ is the sampling frequency.

**EDIT:**
From (1) you can find the index corresponding (approximately) to a given frequency $f$ by

$$i=\left\lfloor\frac{Nf}{f_s}\right\rfloor$$

Note that for a sampling frequency $f_s=19\,\text{kHz}$ your maximum frequency is $19/2=9.5\,\text{kHz}$, so you can't implement the frequency ranges you desire. For the highest band between $6$ and $20\,\text{kHz}$ you need a sampling frequency $f_s>40\,\text{kHz}$.

Comment: Can you show an example of a calculation for second row? `2) 1..3  3`

Comment: @minto: What do you mean? It's up to you to choose the edge frequencies of the bands the way you want them for your application.

Comment: For example, I want to find n-values for 4 channels, the following frequency range: `Low: 0-600 Hz;
Medium1: 600-3,000 Hz;
Medium2: 3,000-6,000 Hz;
High: 6,000-20,000 Hz`

Comment: @minto: That's exactly what you can do with the formula I gave in my answer. Just put in the values for $N$ and $f_s$ and determine the index value $i$ that you want, depending on the frequency you're looking for.

Comment: For more clarity, which frequencies corresponds to values `12..21` in channel 4) in the top?

Comment: @minto: I can't know because I don't know $f_s$ and $N$.

Comment: you said the FFT length N = 128?

Comment: @minto: I guessed so. YOU have to know what your FFT length is.

Comment: The FFT length is 128, the sampling frequency is 19kHz.

Comment: @minto: I've added some information to my answer. You definitely need a higher sampling frequency for the desired frequency bands.

Comment: That's helpful info, thank you. And when sampling rate is 9.6kHz? Also, we limit a useful frequency range to 75Hz - 9,6kHz.

Comment: @minto: Please check out the [sampling theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem). Your sampling frequency must always be greaterh than twice the maximum signal frequency. So if your max. frequency is 9.6kHz, your sampling frequency must be greater than 19.2kHz.